# Babel issue in Monorepo. React, React Native (Expo 50)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, babeljs, monorepo

We have a monorepo: NodeJs, React Native, React

After upgrading to **Expo SDK 50** version we start getting an issue when start frontend server. The frontend server is on React and uses React Native components (via `react-native-web`) from common project's package like `ui`. The `ui` package is common subproject in Monorepo with shared components for web and React Native

The error:

```
ERROR in ../../node_modules/@react-native/assets-registry/registry.js

Module build failed (from ../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/vovborya/code-projects/scrumlaunch/btf/node_modules/@react-native/assets-registry/registry.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'flow' isn't currently enabled (13:8):

  11 | 'use strict';
  12 |
> 13 | export type PackagerAsset = {
     |        ^
  14 |   +__packager_asset: boolean,
  15 |   +fileSystemLocation: string,
  16 |   +httpServerLocation: string,

Add @babel/preset-flow (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-flow) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-flow (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-flow) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

I've already tried to add `@babel/preset-flow`, `@babel/plugin-syntax-flow`, `@babel/preset-typescript` to `babel.config.js` files (there are a few such file in some of project's packages) and nothing helped :(

#### The question: How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This problem exists since Expo SDK 48 -> https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21469

What helped for our project (nx monorepo with Expo app and standalone NextJs web app), was to downgrade "expo-asset" to "~8.7.0".

`npm i expo-asset@~8.7.0`

I'm am currently in the process of migration to Expo SDK 50 (from 47) and faced the same issue.

Hopefully that works for you too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).